# Scipy Optimize - Control the size of the solution array

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am working on an optimization problem similar to portfolio optimization. I have 25 funds with me, but I need allocation only for 10 funds. The optimizer returns me a solution array of just 5. What I need is, the optimizer to allocate for 10 funds based in my objective function.

Is there a way to add this constraint as well?

Comment: I am guessing it is Markowitz portfolio optimization. I've only read about it but for instance in here https://blog.quantopian.com/markowitz-portfolio-optimization-2/ you set the number of assets there. Without your code one can't tell because different models vary.

Comment: Thank you for the reference @Metahominid. I am indeed following the Markowitz model, but instead of using cvxpy, I am using scipy.optimize.minimize.I am not at the liberty to post code here, but there are examples of the same if you browse.

Comment: Well when you load the  https://github.com/omartinsky/QuantAndFinancial/blob/master/black_litterman/black_litterman.ipynb the data you'd get 25 funds, I see that but afterward it is selecting the weights based on the covariance between them. The number of assets in the portfolio is n=len(R). There constraints are put in by the minimize function it seems.

Comment: Choose 5 other funds at random and allocate 1 cent to each.